# Why function working in CodePen but not on GitHub or Locally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, github, codepen

I have a set of functions on my web page used to rotate an icon, and they work on `CodePen` but not on GitHub Pages or when I run it locally. I am using `jQuery` and I'm sure that's linked properly along with the `js` file itself because another function that uses `jQuery` works later on.

Link to Repo: https://github.com/JacobTyBruce/PP

It's the first set of function that modify the arrow icon nav icon. The one to change the PFP works fine.

Comment: Could you also include the codepen link?

Comment: It might have some dependency which you are not including in your local. Check the html setting to find out the included dependency

Comment: It's because of the order of the JS execution; CodePen is by default executing the code in the "JS" panel right before the closing `</body>` tag, whereas locally or on Github pages, your `Main.js` (the same code) is executing where you call it - at the beginning of `<body>` - the elements you are trying to manipulate with jQuery are not yet there in the DOM.

Try moving `<script src="Main.js"></script>` right before `</body>`.